# C program printing a range

Tags: c, printf, range, control-flow

I'm trying to do a simple C program to print grades:

```
int main(void)    
{

    float grade;
    int test;
    printf("Enter your grade:\n");
    test=scanf("%f", &grade);
    if(test!=1 || grade<0.0)
        printf("Error: Please enter a valid grade\n");
    else
    {
        if(grade>4.0)
            printf("Your grade is A+\n");
        else if(grade == 4.0)
            printf("Your grade is A\n");
        else if(grade>=3.7)
            printf("Your grade is A-\n");
        else if(grade>=3.3)
            printf("Your grade is B+\n");
        else if(grade>=3.0)
            printf("Your grade is B\n");
        else if(grade>=2.7)
            printf("Your grade is B-\n");
        else if(grade>=2.3)
            printf("Your grade is C+\n");
        else if(grade>=2.0)
            printf("Your grade is C\n");
        else if(grade>=1.7)
            printf("Your grade is C-\n");
        else if(grade>=1.3)
            printf("Your grade is D+\n");
        else if(grade>=1.0)
            printf("Your grade is D\n");
        else
            printf("Your grade is F\n");
    }

}
```

However when I press 3.3 it prints B instead of B+(and I have the same problem in the rest of the "limits" in my range). Can someone help me fix this? Thanks!

Comment: `3.3` is a double. You may have better luck using `3.3f`in your comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you compare `float` value with `double` type.

use

```
else if(grade>=3.3f)
```

instead of

```
else if(grade>=3.3)
```